# отрицательное число в std::bitset

Tags: c++

Если некоторый обьект  `std::bitset` инициализирован отрицательным числом, как вернуть истинное значение этого числа методами `std::bitset`? Например, есть функция:

```
int foo(int32_t k)
{
    //...
    std::bitset<32> b(k);
    //...
    return b.to_ullong();
}
```

А если  `k` имеет отрицательное значение, как вернуть истинное значение `k`?

P.S.  Вопрос чисто из любопытства и не имеет отношение к какому то реальному коду.

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется, что никак.... По крайней мере, если в него не записан вместе с числом и его знак....

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, но ведь знак - это один из битов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да. Но у bitset размер вроде как произвольный, и если он меньше размера знакового целого, то знак, как понимаю, туда не попадет. А если он на пару бит больше, то у меня, честно говоря, не хватает знаний ,чтобы понять, что получится при преобразованиях туда и обратно.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Если на пару бит больше чем возвращаемый тип, то метод вызовет исключение. А если влезает в беззнаковый, то беззнаковый результат к знаковому можно привести явным приведением, в этом случае все завист от реализации. Скореее всего симметричным способом относительно обратного преобразования, случившегося при инициализации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```cpp
int32_t(b.to_ulong())
```

Comment: Желательно `reinterpret_cast` т.к. знаковый тип меньше беззнакового. А так же  `unsigned long` в общем случае считается больше int32_t

Comment: @Swift, в вопросе `bitset<32>`, так что использование большего типа даст неверный результат.

Comment: Верно, но  я дополню вопрос, потому что на самом деле  наткнулся  на другую ситуацию. Хотя нет, разобрался, спасибо

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, просто я воспользовался типом  std::bitset<8>, поэтому получал другой результат,  а в вопросе написал правильный тип. Ну а теперь наверное неправильно будет дополнять вопрос